# Issue with AJAX and csurf! Invalid csrf token

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, csrf

Trying to send data with ajax, but when i press "send" I have an error in my browser console :
[image]

(and no data is sent)

So I tried different methods from internet, but noone isn't realy help me. And another one issue, ajax trying to send only the half of my data parametrs...[image]

when at least I have more parametrs, like: name and surname .

**Here is my form:**

```
<form action="/user/change" method="post">
    Nickname: <input id="profile_nickname" name='nickname' type="text" value="{{myNickname}}">
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" name='profile_name' value="{{myName}}">
    Surname: <input type="text" id="surname" name="profile_surname" value="{{mySurname}}">
    Age: <input id="profile_age" name="age" type="text" value="{{myAge}}">
    Country: <input type="text" id="profile_country" name="country" value="{{myCountry}}">, 
    City: <input type="text" id="profile_city" name="city" value="{{myCity}}"></li>
    Phone: <input type="text" id="profile_phone" name="phone" value="{{myPhone}}"></li>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value='{{csrfToken}}'>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="send_profile" class="profile-data_submit">
</form>
```

**My AJAX script:**

```
$('#send_profile').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        contentType:"application/x-javascript; charset:UTF-8",
        global: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/user/change',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            name: $("#profile_name").val(),
            nickname: $("#profile_nickname").val(),
            surname: $("#profile_surname").val(),
            country: $("#profile_country").val(),
            city: $("#profile_city").val(),
            phone: $("#profile_phone").val(),
            age: $("#profile_age").val()
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

**And my backend code, that should update data in database:**

```
router.post('/change', function (req, res) {
    var nickname = req.body.nickname,
    name = req.body.name,
    surname = req.body.surname,
    age = req.body.age,
    country = req.body.country,
    city = req.body.city,
    phone = req.body.phone;

    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, {$set:{ nickname: nickname, name: name, surname: surname, age: age, country: country, city: city, phoneNumber: phone }}, {new: true}, function(err, doc){
        if(err){
            console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
        }
    });

});
```

It woorks pretty good without AJAX, but I need refresh data without page reloading...